# Is there another safer solution for accessing remotely to sql server than 'username'@'%'?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to access mysql server in office remotely from home by mysql workbench.

I already solved to connect remotely. I created an user by:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'myusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

And, with this user, I can access the database remotely. But, I don't think it's safe. `@'%'` means that all hosts can access once they find out `'myusername'` and `'some_pass'`.

Instead of that, I would like to get it done by an user whose IP is specified. (after removing the user above), I created the user below by:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'myusername'@'123.456.789.012' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

'123.456.789.012' here is the IP address of my home computer.(the number is dummy, though.). With user like this, it allows only the specified host to access. I think it is safer. But, I have already tried this and didn't work. I got the error below on mysql workbench on home computer when trying to connect remotely (by test connection from mysql workbench):

```
    Failed to Connect to MySQL at XXX.XX.XX.XXX:3306 with user myname

Host 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XX-XX.abc.defg.hi.jk' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I don't know why this error pops up.

and also, I tried the user with IP addresses like `'123.456.789.%'` or `'%.456.789.012'` which got the same error.

Is there another way to accomplish remote connection safer?

Comment: Are you asking if it's safe to not restrict server access by IP or attempting to solve your issues when trying?

Comment: How are you trying to access it remotely? Workbench?

Comment: You would be better to SSH into the server as that is secure. The connection you make from home could be secure but could also be insecure. You dont say how you are doing that

Comment: The main issue here is someone sniffing your password as it traverses the net. If your connection to the server is insecure, the password escapes, and anyone from anywhere can use it if you have allowed it to be used from any domain

Comment: What is the error you get? Is it the Public IP? Also, is the connectivity intact between the Db and your host?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Was a mistake, I changed.I somehow missed to comment.

Comment: No problem :):)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am asking if it's safe to not restrict server access by IP. `@'%' ` solved remote connection to sql server, but it means it allows all hosts to have the chance to connect to this sql server. And, I am curious about if there is another safer solution to connect remotely.

Comment: @LV98 I am trying to connect by mysql workbench.

Comment: I updated OP entirely to get it more focus on one question.

Comment: That's easy then. Internet is world-wide so if you allow connections from anywhere that means that leaked or guessed passwords can be abused by anyone. A safer solution? You can restrict access by IP address so you get covered in such event. Safer than that? You can encrypt the connection. Even safer? Firewall, hardware tokens... You can trade convenience for security as much as it's worth it for your particular use case.

Comment: I've just noticed you edited the second question you weren't really asking. `'123.456.789.012'` is different from `'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx'`. I understand both values are redacted. I don't know if original values are different too. Do you have a fixed public IP address?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I modified ''xxx.xx.xxx.xxx'' with ''123.456.789.012''. I don't have a fixed public IP address but I am ok to set updated IP address on the sql server side everytime my public IP address changed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález 'You can restrict access by IP address so you get covered in such event.' I am trying doing this as I mentioned on OP, I tried to set user IP address to '123.456.789.012' or '123.456.789.%' or '%.456.789.012'. But none of them doesn't work.

Comment: My servers return a message like `Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` when user host is wrong, which is different from what you get. I suspect you need to configure something else on the server or perhaps create a firewall rule. I can't really help with that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am sorry. As for the error message, I updated.